# Finding the Nth character in a string and printing it MIPS32 assembler

Tags: assembly, mips32

Ok so i have a simple program where given an integer as input by the user,suppose its X,tries to find the character at X position in a string.Works fine, but there is a little bug.As its easy to see,string length is 26 so if user enters for example 0->a must be printed, and so it does.But if i enter a number bigger than 25(since 1st char is at position 0) no errors appear....For example if i enter 40 i get as a result character e...Can somebody help me?
As.Here is my code:

```
.text           
.globl main
main:
    li $s3,26 #string length


    la $a0, str1    # Load and print string asking for integer
    li $v0, 4
    syscall  

    li $v0,5 
    syscall
    add $s0 ,$v0, $zero #integer now in $s0



    la $a1,str #address of string now is $a1
    addu $a1,$a1,$s0   # $a1 = &str[x].  assumes x is in $s0
    lbu $a0,($a1)      # read the character
    li $v0,11
    syscall            # and print it







     li $v0,10
    syscall     



.data
str: .asciiz "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwzyz"
str1: .asciiz "give an integer: "
```

Comment: Check the range of the integer *before* you add the string address.

Comment: that will work but my question is why does this happen...makes no sense to me to give as input a number bigger than the string length and not receive an error...

Comment: The processor will read whatever memory location you tell it to read (bar access permission). The index of `40` has picked out an `'e'` from the *next* string in memory at `str1: .asciiz "give an integer: "`

Comment: Ah now it makes sense....thanks a lot,if you want you can write official answer so i can accept it,if not its ok, still you helped me in a great way!!

Comment: In ASM memory is not protected per "variable", as that `str` is not even variable, or "string" type, the assembler doesn't know such things. `str:` is label pointing to the next defined byte. The next defined byte happens to be `'a'` defined by the `.asciiz "abc...."`. That's all what assembler understands about symbol `str`, that it points at byte with `'a'`. It has no idea another 25 letters follow with zero terminator. That's up to your code to give those bytes some structure and meaning, like going char by char from index 0 and looking for zero terminator or reaching desired index.

Comment: Or as you put length of string into $s3 manually, you can check against that one, but that's not as flexible, needs refresh every time you will change the `str` data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The processor will read whatever memory location you tell it to read (bar access permission). The index of `40` has picked out an `'e'` from the *next* string in memory at

```
str1: .asciiz "give an integer: "
```

Best thing is to check the range of the number that was input. Assembly language has none of the inbuilt safeguards that higher lever languages have - only memory access constraints, implemented in the hardware.

**Edit:** There *are* other inbuilt safeguards in the processor, but they are not "language" oriented. Processors may have a **watchdog** that requires regular kicking to make sure the program has not got stuck somewhere that the programmer did not intend. **Divide by zero** is another. But the processor's response is brutal, and does not help the program's flow of logic at all.

Generally, the only error handling your assembly program gets is that picked up by the asembler itself, and what you code into the program. So if you want an error for an out of range index - that's your job.

These are the basic reasons why higher level languages evolved.